# ImageView centered image with mach_parent height

Tags: android, imageview

I need to create ImageView for portrait mode like on this image: 
[image]

But whatever I do I got same results like: 
[image]

**EDITED**
`XML` example from  third image

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:src="@drawable/background" />
```

Comment: please post your xml that is responsible for this part

Comment: post your complete layout.xml file please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few possibilities that may cause this problem. You either have a Margin set for your image (margin top and bottom). Or the parent layout has a padding (also top and bottom).

You only need to remove this padding or margin in order for the view to fill the parent layout.

There's also another possibility, which -by looking at your code- might be the issue. you might want to use `android:background` attribute instead of `android:src`

Comment: Thanks, it's working. I added layout_marginTop="0dp" and layout_marginBottom="0dp" and it's works as I want. I will rate U in a 5-6 minutes.

Comment: I don't understand the "to change visible part of image" part, but anyway that's a different question, please start a new post to ask that question :)